# Profile in ISPF gets changed to COBOL (VARIABLE 80)

Tags: eclipse, cobol, ispf

I'm having problems with the ISPF editor.
When I signin a program from Eclipse to Endevor it sometimes changes the profile from COBOL (FIXED 80) to COBOL (VARIABLE 80).

```
****** ***************************** Top of Data ******************************
=PROF> ....COBOL (VARIABLE - 80)....RECOVERY ON....NUMBER ON STD...............
=PROF> ....CAPS OFF....HEX OFF....NULLS ON STD....TABS OFF.....................
=PROF> ....AUTOSAVE ON....AUTONUM ON....AUTOLIST OFF....STATS OFF..............
=PROF> ....PROFILE UNLOCK....IMACRO NONE....PACK OFF....NOTE ON................
=PROF> ....HILITE COBOL CURSOR FIND............................................
==MSG> *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
==MSG> *                                                                     *
==MSG> *  This element is referenced by no other elements.                   *
==MSG> *                                                                     *
==MSG> *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

Does anyone know how to change the profile to FIXED?

**Solution:**
It's not something the profile does, it's the underlying file that is changed in the Eclipse/Endevor interaction.

Solved it by:
1. Copying all code to a new fixed dataset
2. Deleting all rows on the original file
3. Making appropriate changes to the profile
4. Copying the code back to the original file
5. Making necessary adjustments to horizontal alignment.

Comment: ISPF is telling you that the underlying data set is variable, with 80 bytes (actually LRECL 84). The name of the data set being edited appears above the command line, which is the line immediately above the "top of data" line. Is it a PDS member or a sequential file, and if the latter, is it a permanent dataset or a temporary dataset (like SYSyyddd.Thhmmss.RAnnn.userid.something)?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an ISPF issue.  Like zarchasmpgmr stated, the fixed or variable should be based on the file being edited as it is opened and read in.   You can verify by checking the actual file as he stated.  It sounds like you need to check out how the Eclipse to Endevor sign-in procedure is done to see why it creates a variable file in certain cases.   Perhaps the underlying Eclipse file format is different for certain releases , workspaces, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are correct, anyhow I solved it by: 
1. Copying all code to a new fixed dataset
2. Deleting all rows on the original file
3. Making appropriate changes to the profile
4. Copying the code back to the original file
5. Making necessary adjustments to horizontal alignment.